# ProtoBuf.js how to filter extra fields when encoding an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, protocol-buffers

I'm using [Protobuf.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js) to write a hook for sails.js to be able to send message encoded by protocol buffers by socket.io.

Say I have a proto scheme `Message.proto`:

```
message Message{
    required string message = 1;
    optional string user = 2;
    optional int32 id = 3;
}
```

And I'm getting an object from database as `data`:

```
data = { 
  message: 'Hello',
  user: 'johnDoe',
  id: 90,
  createdAt: '2015-10-16T10:15:39.837Z',
  updatedAt: '2015-10-16T10:15:39.837Z' 
};
```

And I have a [sails hook](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks) with code:

```
var ProtoBuf = require("protobufjs"),
    Reflect = ProtoBuf.Reflect,
    builder = ProtoBuf.newBuilder(),
    protoModels;

...

    // This method overrides socket.io broadcast call for sails.js models pubSub:
    augmentModels: function () {
        for (var identity in app.models) {
            var protobufSchemeName = app.models[identity].protobufSchemeName;
            // protobufSchemeName is the file name of the sheme
            if (protobufSchemeName) {
                ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile(path.join(app.config.appPath, app.config.protobuf.folder, protobufSchemeName + ".proto"), builder);
                app.models[identity].broadcast = function (roomName, eventName, data, socketToOmit) {
                    var dataToSend = protoModels[protobufSchemeName].encode(???HERE???); //HERE I SHOULD PUT THE MODIFIED DATA WITH THE ONLY NECESSARY FIELDS
                    app.sockets.broadcast(roomName, eventName, dataToSend.toBuffer(), socketToOmit);
                };
            }
            protoModels = builder.build();
        }
    }
```

I can't pass `data` directly this way: `protoModels[protobufSchemeName].encode(data)` because it will cause an error: `this+"#"+keyOrObj+" is not a field`, because data contains extra fields;

So **here goes the question**: what is the easiest and correct way to save to `dataToSend` only fields that are in the scheme (`Message.proto`)?

P.S. I know that should have something with [Reflection](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/wiki/Reflection) and they say you can do it like this way:

```
var TPlayer = builder.lookup("Game.Player"); // instance of ProtoBuf.Reflect.Message

var fields = TPlayer.getChildren(ProtoBuf.Reflect.Message.Field); // instances of ProtoBuf.Reflect.Message.Field
fields.forEach(function(field) {
    //Filter it here
});
```

But I can't figure it out how to to reach `lookup` method from `protoModels`. And maybe there is the way to use [Builder's](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/master/docs/ProtoBuf.Builder.html) isMessageField method to filter fields in `data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We still have a builder there so the solution is quite the same as in [example](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/wiki/Reflection):

```
...
augmentModels: function () {
        for (var identity in app.models) {
            var protobufSchemeName = app.models[identity].protobufSchemeName;
            if (protobufSchemeName) {
                ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile(path.join(app.config.appPath, app.config.protobuf.folder, protobufSchemeName + ".proto"), builder);
                app.models[identity].broadcast = function (roomName, eventName, data, socketToOmit) {
                    var fields = builder.lookup(protobufSchemeName).getChildren(ProtoBuf.Reflect.Message.Field).map(function (f) {
                        return f.name;
                    }); //Here are the fieldnames of the scheme as an array
                    var dataToSend = protoModels[protobufSchemeName].encode(_.pick(data, fields)).toBuffer();
                    app.sockets.broadcast(roomName, eventName, dataToSend, socketToOmit);
                };
            }
            protoModels = builder.build();
        }
    }
```

Another way is to override emit/broadcast methods like I did in the hook below:

**P.S. If anyone will find this useful:**

I've made a [Protobuf Serialization Hook](https://github.com/elennaro/sails-hook-socket-protobuf) for Sails.js. Contributions are welcome!